Fullcalendar show modal from url
I'm using Fullcalendar and everything is working fine, I have a weekly calendar with events and when I click on an event than a modal shows with more information about this event.
Let say I show this calendar from the url https://test.com/fullcalendar.php
I want to add some extra functions to this so that the modal of the event with ID 123 is showing when I go the to url https://test.com/fullcalendar.php?id=123, thus without clicking on the event in the calendar.
Is this possible?

Most things are possible, yes. Have you tried anything? Where are you getting stuck? Just write some code which looks to see if an id parameter is in the URL parameters and, if it is, runs the code which normally displays the modal immediately, passing in the relevant ID. Obviously I don't know precisely how your modal code works currently or what code you use to trigger it. Nor do I know if you were wanting to do this task in PHP or JavaScript, or anything else - you didn't share anything from your existing code. If you want more specific help [edit] your question with relevant code. Thanks

You are right, I didn't share a lot of needful information, my bad .... I have done some search on this topic but can't find anything related to this so I was hoping that someone recognize this. Fullcalendar is a great tool in JS but with the pop-ups it isn't very easy to work with if you want some data from a MySQL database being presented in this modal. But I have given it some thoughts last weekend and I think I am going to take another solution which doesn''t need Fullcalendar and get this done in plain PHP / MySQL in a new page.

with the pop-ups it isn't very easy to work with if you want some data from a MySQL database being presented in this modal....you can use AJAX anytime to get the data from the server. That can happen whether you are using fullCalendar, or not using it. I don't see how fullCalendar could be a barrier to that.
